# tcl clock scan snmp Date Time format

Tags: datetime, tcl, snmp

The standard `snmp` `DateTime` format is as below.

http://net-snmp.sourceforge.net/docs/mibs/host.html#DateAndTime

```
"2016-10-3,2:15:27.0,-4:0"
```

Now I'm trying to convert this value into `epoch` using tcl's `clock scan`

The formatting options in [here](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/clock.htm#M26) for scanning does not support fractional seconds and time zone I think.

```
% clock scan $value2 -format {%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}
input string does not match supplied format
```

I've managed to split the values into date, time and timeZone.

```
% set value "2016-10-3,2:15:27.0,-4:0"
2016-10-3,2:15:27.0,-4:0
% set value [split $value ,]
2016-10-3 2:15:27.0 -4:0
% lassign $value date time timeZone
%
```

How do I proceed after this?

Comment: Timezones might be supported (`%z` and `%Z) but only with a different format. There's a limit to how many odd formats can be supported…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first part that is a problem is the fractional second. Also, the timezone is not in a form that we can support (there's only so much we can do; we focused on making the parser able to handle common parts of the ISO timestamp format).

However, that does mean we can clean things up fairly easily. There's a few steps to this, and we'll use `regexp`, `scan` and `format` to help:

```
# Your example, in a variable for my convenience
set instant "2016-10-3,2:15:27.0,-4:0"

# Take apart the problem piece; REs are *great* for string parsing!
regexp {^(.+)\.(\d+),(.+)$} $instant -> timepart fraction timezone

# Fix the timezone format; we use [scan] for semantic parsing...
set timezone [format "%+03d%02d" {*}[scan $timezone "%d:%d"]]

# Parse the time properly now that we can understand all the pieces
set timestamp [clock scan "$timepart $timezone" -format "%Y-%m-%d,%k:%M:%S %z"]
```

Let's check whether that produces the right sort of output (this is in an interactive session):

```
% clock format $timestamp
Mon Oct 03 07:15:27 BST 2016
```

Looks good to me. I suppose you could add the fractional part of the original instant on the end, but then `clock format` wouldn't like it.

Answer (score 2):

You could proceed like this (checking scan results for each step: neither of these is of course the final result):

```
clock scan $date -format %Y-%N-%e

lassign [split $time .] t d
clock scan $t -format %k:%M:%S
```

You'll have to decide what to do with the deci-second part (in `d`).

```
lassign [split $timeZone :] h m ; # or:
scan $timeZone %d:%d h m
clock scan [format {%+03d%02d} $h $m] -format %z
```

Exactly what `clock` field specifiers to use depends on the basic format: adjust as needed. AFAICT these specifiers match the format.

To get the final time value:

```
clock scan "$date $t [format {%+03d%02d} $h $m]" -format "%Y-%N-%e %k:%M:%S %z"
```

Documentation:
[clock](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/clock.htm),
[format](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/format.htm),
[lassign](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lassign.htm),
[scan](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/scan.htm),
[split](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/split.htm)

Comment: Thanks to both of you. Now I'm confused about which one to accept.

Comment: Note that if the hour/minute parts of the time zone can have leading zeroes, you should use scan to extract them, as in Donal's answer. If not, a simple split will work. The reason is that 08 and 09 are read as (illegal) octal numbers, but scan %d specifies decimal.

Comment: @thiru: well, mine does too :)